# Comma Delimited Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I need a regex to test strings like these:

```
`8 - 12`
`8-12`
`8,9,10,11,12`
`8, 9, 10, 11, 12`
```

It would need to test if a given input meets the above format, either giving a range of numbers (say 8 through 12) denoted by hyphen-separated limits, or a comma-separated list of numbers.  In both cases, spaces should be ignored.

Where do I start?

Comment: Should `8-12,5,6` match? Or only ever one format per string?

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
\d+\s?[-,]?\s?
```

perhaps?

Comment: Forgot to mention, this is in JavaScript. Trying to tweak the mentioned expression but having trouble

Comment: Make sure you put the pattern between two forward slashes like so:
/\d+\s?[-,]?\s?/g

The g is a flag meaning "global search". Are you trying to pull any data with this expression or just checking the input to make sure it matches?

Answer (score 0):

This expression should do the job `/(^\d+\s*?\-\s*?\d+$)|(^\d+(\s*?\,\s*?\d+|$)*$)/`

Answer (score 0):

To increase legibility of the regular expressions, I would recommend removing spaces before the check - depending on iteration count/data size, the separate call shouldn't have a noticeable performance impact.

A simple answer:

```
var str = '8 - 12';
str = str.replace(/\s+/g,'');
var matches = (/^\d+([,-]\d+)+$/).test(str); //Will allow "8-12,13"
```

A less forgiving answer:

```
var str = '8 - 12';
str = str.replace(/\s+/g,'');
var matches = (/^\d+(-\d+|(,\d+)+)$/).test(str); //Won't allow mixed formats
```

If you're not checking the whole string, you can of course remove the `^` and `$` from the expressions, i.e. `\d+([,-]\d+)+`